nw_connection_copy_connected_local_endpoint_block_invoke [C35] Connection has no local endpoint
I have an app which makes some requests in the background when launching it and navigating through the views. There are many endpoints requested.
I get this warning message many times printed in the Xcode Console:

What is the reason for these warnings?
How can I debug this?

I've had the same problem for a few months. As I'm sure someone will say: it is just a warning so it probably isn't negatively impacting app performance. But it overwhelms my logs and now I miss important log messages. I spent a day commenting out major parts of my code and couldn't find the source. So I agree that even debugging strategies would be welcome.
